# Cant catch response after post request fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise, axios

I send a request like this

```
try {
 const res = await axios.post('/order', formData)

 console.log(res) --> undefined
 console.log(test1) --> it is on console
}
catch (error) {
 console.log(test2)
}
```

but for some reason even I get 500 from request, test1 and undefined are on console. Why is this happening even it is an error. Shouldnt it go to catch?

--- SOLUTION ---

I found what is wrong after 4 days. After I removed axios.interceptor from code everything works as expected

Comment: Usually with Promises you do `.post().catch(function () {console.log(test2)})`, not with try/catch, as your try/catch is executed sync

Comment: Even I use 
axios
    .post('/order', formData)
    .then((res) => console.log('test1'))
    .catch((err) => console.log('test2'))

I get test1 on console ( Still getting 500 from request ).
 I get error from server, how can it go to then block. Really weird

Comment: @Justinas With `await` you should be able to use `try/catch` as like as you use `then/catch`. If the promise reject you will end up in the `catch` branch. I would check if the real status code of the response is 500, and not some other header maybe

Comment: @DDomen I opened network and Its status 500 .Also there is an error which says my formData is wrong. How can it behave like success?

Comment: By the way even it goes to then block, it doesnt return anything my res is undefined